# How to calculate a new lat long based on distance from a point

Tags: c#, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to calculate a new lat long from a point based on a distance in metres from that point.

I've found a few posts on here and elsewhere that helped, but I'm still having a little trouble.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
        public LatLon CalculateNewCoords(decimal startingLat, decimal startingLon, int distanceEast, int distanceNorth)
    {
        int r = 6378137;
        decimal dLat = Convert.ToDecimal(distanceNorth) / Convert.ToDecimal(r);

        decimal pi = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.PI);
        double cosInput = Convert.ToDouble(pi * startingLat / Convert.ToDecimal(180));

        decimal dLon = Convert.ToDecimal(distanceEast) / Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDouble(r) * Math.Cos(cosInput));

        decimal lat0 = startingLat + dLat * (180 * pi);
        decimal lon0 = startingLon + dLon * (180 / pi);     

        LatLon output = new LatLon();
        output.Latitude = lat0;
        output.Longitude = lon0;

        return output;
    }
```

The longitude seems correct, but the latitude is displaying quite significantly out.

I'm using it as follows:

```
CalculateNewCoords(Convert.ToDecimal(40.743461), Convert.ToDecimal(-74.175847), 0, 1000);
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the first line:

```
    decimal lat0 = startingLat + dLat * (180 * pi);
    decimal lon0 = startingLon + dLon * (180 / pi);
```

this is fore sure not correct, both lines must use the same radians to degrees conversion.
Replace with 180/pi like in line 2.
further think on using double instead if decimal.

Comment: More precisely, they should both be `180 / pi`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.
***edit***
Just saw the comment, thanks.
Tried it and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Decimal isa lot better than double for his purpose.

Comment: why do you think that? for sure it is not, see the unreadable code, even float would be sufficient enough

Comment: Just wanted to jump in here.  Precision is quite important to me.  I need to find all other points within 10 metres of another point, so the more precise I can be the better.
As for the unreadable code, I'll be cleaning it up, I was just struggling to figure out what was going wrong :P

Comment: when you talk about precision, you should know what precision you  need for the calculated point. Your formula is an aproximation which does not account for the curvature of the earth and therfore much worse than the difference between decimal and double. your formula gets worse for rasing distances. it is usefull for small distance, for distance over some miles, ten miles, it becomes less acurate. you can try ot out. the difference between decimal and doible would be less than 1/billion of a milimeter.